# Get actual code number value from combobox in datagridview, not column's name

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I create a combobox column in a datagridview which I populate it from a database. But what I want to do now is to get the actual code number value from the selected item so that I can use it as in a normal combobox. The problem is that whenever I select an item from the list I get the column's name: "Code" where the code number value is located instead of the code number value.

Please help me out, this is my code:

```
    private void Invoice_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Logic.Repair objRepair = new Logic.Repair();

        public DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dgvCB = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

        dgvCB.Name = "Repair";
        dgvCB.HeaderText="Repair";
        dgvCB.DataSource = objRepair.AllRepairQuery();
        dgvCB.DisplayMember = "Repair";
        dgvCB.ValueMember = "Code"; //this is what I keep geting, the word "Code"
                    //what I want to get is the code number value not the column's name.
        dgvRepair.Columns.Add(dgvCB);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

"AllRepairQuery" is a method which returns a datatable from database using "select * from repair" and it returns all the fields including the code

Comment: Have you debugged to see if your datasource is correct? Sounds like code is just not there

Comment: What is the return type of "AllRepairQuery" ?

Comment: "AllRepairQuery" is a method which returns a datatable from database using "select * from repair" and it returns all the fields including the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the following code:

```
int SelectedVal = Convert.ToInt32(dgvReparair.Rows[dgvRepair.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells["Repair"].Value);
```